# How to stop and then start a map service using the model builder

Tags: arcgis-server, modelbuilder

Is it possible to stop a map service using a geoprocessing tool in the model builder ? If not How can I stop a map service using a model builder ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to stop/start a map service with a Python code that can be built into a Python script tool in toolbox. You can then drag this tool into the ModelBuilder and embed it into the model.

You can also just run the tool as is. The toolbox is called 
[ArcGIS Server Administration Toolkit - 10.1+](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=12dde73e0e784e47818162b4d41ee340) which you can download. There is already a model which shows how to use the tools.

[image]